# Corona SDK Touch Phases - Touch and Hold

Tags: coronasdk

I am trying to make a game in Corona where if I tap and hold the screen the wheel will rotate but it only rotates when i keep tapping the screen how to I change this so that as long as my finger is pressed on the screen, the wheel will rotate? Here is my code:

```
local physics = require "physics"
physics.start()

--Variables 

--[bike = display.newImage("bike.png")
--bike.x = 70
--bike.y = 290
--physics.addBody(bike, {friction = 0.3, bounce = 0.2})

wheel1 = display.newImage("wheel.png")
wheel1.x = 480 / 2
wheel1.y = 320 / 2

wheel2 = display.newImage("wheel.png")
wheel2.x = 480 / 2 + 50
wheel2.y = 320 / 2 - 50

driveBtn = display.newImage("drive.png")


local function driveFunction( event )


    wheel1.rotation = wheel1.rotation + 3
    wheel2.rotation = wheel2.rotation + 3


end


Runtime:addEventListener("touch", driveFunction)
```

Comment: [ot] hello and welcome to SO. I wish I'd be able to code for corona SDK at the age of 14 so, yeah, I guess that's pretty good!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very simple solution. By the way, its very good that you started to developing in an early age, keep coding^^ If you dont understand the code below or logic behind it, just post a comment and ask.

```
local physics = require "physics"
physics.start()

--Variables 

--[bike = display.newImage("bike.png")
--bike.x = 70
--bike.y = 290
--physics.addBody(bike, {friction = 0.3, bounce = 0.2})

local wheel1 = display.newImage("wheel.png")
wheel1.x = 480 / 2
wheel1.y = 320 / 2

local wheel2 = display.newImage("wheel.png")
wheel2.x = 480 / 2 + 50
wheel2.y = 320 / 2 - 50

local driveBtn = display.newImage("drive.png")

local function rotateWheel()
      wheel1.rotation = ( wheel1.rotation + 3 ) % 360
      wheel2.rotation = ( wheel2.rotation + 3 ) % 360
end

local function driveFunction( event )
     if event.phase == "began" then
          display.getCurrentStage():setFocus( wheel1 )
          wheel1.isFocus = true
          Runtime:addEventListener( "enterFrame", rotateWheel )
     elseif wheel1.isFocus then              
          if event.phase == "moved" then
          elseif event.phase == "ended" then
               Runtime:removeEventListener( "enterFrame", rotateWheel )
               display.getCurrentStage():setFocus( nil )
               wheel1.isFocus = false
          end
     end
end

Runtime:addEventListener( "touch", driveFunction )
```

Comment: Okay thanks for the reply! but the simulator loads the main.lua file perfectly fine but when i click on the screen an error comes up:   Line: 30

Attempt to index field 'target' (a nil value)    i dont get it, I have tried to fix it numerous times but no luck :/